# Assign JQuery Selector to a Variable Once

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery plugin function where I would like to assign selectors from an iframe just once, and then use them throughout the plugin.

In the basic example below, if I have a function within the plugin it won't work for the $modal selector unless I explicitly set it within the function.

Is there any way to do this so that I can assign the selector to a variable just once and have it accessible throughout the plugin function?

```
jQuery.customPlugin = function() {


    var $modal = $('#modal', frames['admin-bar'].document);


    $('#hide-modal').click(function(){

        hide_modal();

    });

    // doesn't work - but I want it to somehow
    function hide_modal(){

        $modal.hide();

    }

    // works, but requires lots of re-querying if I have lots of selectors/functions
    function hide_modal(){

        var $modal = $('#modal', frames['admin-bar'].document);
        $modal.hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: you may also want to look into underscore.js - it provides nice solutions to these types of issues. (though its no substitue for knowing javascript)

Comment: While I love Underscore, and would recommend the library to any JS developer, I don't see how it could help with this issue.  None of the awesome tricks in Underscore (binding, iterator methods, etc.) would help keep a jQuery selector from getting "stale".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery selectors query the DOM when you instantiate them.  In other words, if you do `var $foo = $('.bar')`, and then add a new element with class "bar" to the page, your $foo variable won't include it.  This is just how jQuery works.

What you can do is write a method get$Modal, which re-queries every time you run it.  For instance:

```
function get$Modal() {
    return $('#modal', frames['admin-bar'].document);
}
// Should work
function hide_modal(){
    get$Modal().hide();
}
```

Alternatively, what you can also do is "register" your modals as you create them, avoiding the need to re-query.  Something like:

```
var $modals = $('.modal');// start with any existing modals
function createModal() {
    var $modal = generateModal();
    modals.add($modal); // add any newly created modals
}

// Should work
function hide_modal(){
    $modals.hide();
}
```

That should work great if you have a common place where all modals are created.  If you create modals in many different places, you might want to use a custom event to organize things:

```
var $modals = $('.modal');// start with any existing modals
$(document.body).on('newModal', function(e, $newModal) {
    $modals.add($newModal);
})

function createModalPlace1() {
    var $modal = generateModal();
    $(document.body).trigger('newModal', $modal)
}

function createModalPlace2() {
    var $modal = generateModalSomeOtherWay();
    $(document.body).trigger('newModal', $modal)
}

function createModalPlace3() { // etc.
```